# Gutenberg InnerBlocks with ACF Blocks - How to enable multiple buttons?

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to use Gutenberg's [InnerBlocks](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/e7fbb88180f53acc77acf4c0c3859e81675ab4de/docs/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates.md) with [ACF Blocks](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block_type/) in my `allowedBlocks` I have `[ 'core/heading', 'core/paragraph', 'core/buttons']` In my 'core/buttons' block I'd like to allow multiple buttons, but it only seems to enable one.

My block `template` is as follows:

```
[
    [
         'core/heading',
         [
             'level'       => 3,
             'placeholder' => __( "Add Heading...", THEMENAME ),
             'align'       => 'center',
             'className'   => 'has-text-align-center',
         ],
     ],
    [
          'core/paragraph',
          [
               'placeholder' => __( "Add paragraph text...", THEMENAME ),
               'align'       => 'center',
          ],
    ],
    [
          'core/buttons',
          [
               'align'       => 'center',
          ],
    ],
]
```

Additionally the align 'center' doesn't seem to work for this block.

Comment: It seems the immediate issue is resolved by removing `templateLock="all"` on `<InnerBlocks />`. However, I'd still like to lock the template but allow multiple buttons. Still can't get them centered by default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a look at this site:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/#buttons

You can see that "Core/Buttons" (plural) only supports "full/wide" on "align". You can however use "align" => "center" on "core/button".
I don't know how you can add multiple buttons inside "core/buttons", but you can however add multiple "core/button" inside your template:

```
[ 'core/button', [ 'align' => 'center' ] ],
[ 'core/button', [ 'align' => 'center' ] ],
```

Hope this helps!